# Known "position:relative" issues in Firefox 2.x?

Tags: firefox, css

Virgin post.

Are there any known issues with how FF2/Windows handles div's positioned relative?

IEx / Chrome on Windows, FF3x / Safari 4x on Mac are rendering fine. and I would think IE for sure would have barked at me if the coding was incorrect.

```
<!--example-->
#parent_div {width:200px; height:100px; position:relative;}
#child_div {width:100px; height:50px; position:absolute;}
```

`<div>`
 `<div id="parent_div">`
   `<div id="inner_div">foobar</div>`
 `</div>`
`</div>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any errors. Your example renders the same for me in IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari. The name mismatch between ‘child_div’ versus ‘inner_div’ may be a problem, but fixing that still results in the same layout over all browsers.

Comment: Thank you. Previous code was just an example. 

This is the actual code - 

http://www.profootballweekly.com/

Specifically, the live scores widget across the top of the site. In FF2(0.0.20) the widget flys out to the right of the page.

Comment: This is caused by a float just above the widget having ‘float: left’. Firefox is trying to position the widget in the space to the right of the nav instead of below it. Can be fixed by telling the widget to ‘clear: left’.